# What is a Random Effect Predictor in lmer

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I would like to understand the meaning of the term "random effect", in the context of running a mixed effect model with lme4's lmer() function.

I have several related questions, so I will walk through a contrived example, and pose several questions at the end.

---

**i)  Making an Example Dataset**

I will create an example dataset having two predictors:

- Subject :: Categorical, Unordered
- Days :: Numerical

And one response:

- Response :: Numerical, Gaussian distributed

| Subject | Days | Response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 250 |
| A | 4 | 210 |
| A | 8 | 190 |
| B | 0 | 300 |
| B | 4 | 310 |
| B | 8 | 300 |
| C | 0 | 350 |
| C | 4 | 400 |
| C | 8 | 460 |

*Note that this example dataset is analogous to lme4's builtin "sleepstudy" dataset, used in the "Fitting Linear Mixed-Effects Models Using lme4" document by Bates et al. (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf))*

---

**ii) Philosophy of Treating each Predictor as Fixed or Random Effect**

*Subject Predictor*

If the levels of Subject were chosen non-randomly, i.e. specific people were selected for the study, then I should treat Subject as a Fixed Effect predictor.

However, if the levels of Subject were chosen at random, i.e. people were randomly selected for inclusion in the study, then I should treat Subject as a Random Effect predictor.

*Days Predictor*

If the levels of Days were chosen non-randomly, then I should treat Days as a Fixed Effect predictor.

If the levels of Days were chosen randomly, then I should treat Days as a Random Effect predictor.

---

**iii) Mixed Effect Model with lmer()**

The model for an experiment like this, given in the "Fitting Linear Mixed-Effects Models Using lme4" document, is:

> lmer( Response ~ Days + (1+Days|Subject) )

The Fixed Effects design matrix has one column of 1's to estimate the overall grand intercept:

[image]

And one column of covariate values to estimate the overall grand slope for Days:

[image]

The Random Effects design matrix has six columns total, two per Subject level.

For each Subject level, there is a column of 1's to estimate the deviation of its intercept, i.e. the amount of deviation away from the Fixed Effect overall grand intercept.

[image]

For each Subject level, there is a column of the numerical Days covariate values, for which the column's associated parameter will estimate the deviation of the Days-slope for that Subject level, i.e. the amount of deviation away from the Fixed Effect overall grand Days slope.

[image]

---

**iv) Questions**

***Question 1 - Random Effect Categorical Predictors***

For categorical predictors that are treated as random effects, what part of them should be thought of as random?

In my example, there is a single random effect, Subject, with three levels, A, B, and C. This corresponds to the three columns of 1's in the random effect design matrix, each of which will be multiplied by a model parameter, where the model parameter estimates the intercept effect for each Subject level.

Thus, should I think of all three columns of 1's in the random effects design matrix as being part of a single random variable, the Subject? Where the three parameters are considered as instantiations of a single random variable?

[image]

Or should I think of each model parameter as a random variable on its own, in which case there are three separate random variables, one for each level of Subject.

[image]

***Question 2 - Random Effect Numerical Predictors***

Although not featured in this example, I am curious if it is ever possible to have a Numerical predictor that is a random effect?

From the philosophical point of view it seems just as valid, since I could imagine measuring a numerical variable as a random covariate, like rainfall, and including that in an experiment design along with another predictor, like fertilizer brand, as might occur in a farming study.

In such a case however, there would be only a single column for the numerical predictor in the random effect design matrix. Does this mean that lmer() would treat that column's associated model parameter as the random variable?

[image]

Or would lmer() look at the measured values, i.e. levels, of the numerical covariate itself?

[image]

Thus, Question 2 is related to Question 1, with both relating to: what exactly does lmer() consider to be a random variable, and what information does lmer() use to calculate the variance of the random variable.

***Question 3 - Days is not a Random Effect, but Days:Subject Interaction is Random Effect***

In this example, the predictor Days is treated as a fixed effect, based on the philosophical reason that its numerical levels are specifically chosen, and not randomly sampled. Thus, it is entered in the lmer() formula as a fixed effect. However, the numerical information from the Days predictor still ends up in the random effects design matrix.

It seems the reason why this is acceptable is because it is not actually the Days predictor that is in the random effect design matrix. Rather, a new predictor is implicitly created by lmer() due to the model formula specification placing Days to the left side of the pipe character in Subject's random effect term, i.e. (Days|Subject).

In this situation, what is the correct way to discuss Days?

Is it best to say that Days is a Fixed Effect, but the implicitly created interaction predictor Days:Subject is a Random Effect?

***Question 4 - Categorical:Numerical Interaction Predictor***

In the case of the implicit interaction predictor Days:Subject described in Question 3, what exactly is the random variable estimated by lmer()?

In this example, the implicit Days:Subject interaction predictor gets three columns in the random effects design matrix, since it is the interaction between a Categorical predictor with three levels and a Numerical predictor.

Are the three parameters treated as instantiations of a single random variable?

[image]

Is each column's parameter treated as a separate random variable?

[image]

Or are the numerical values themselves used to calculate the random variable and its properties?

[image]

***Question 5 - Numerical:Numerical Interaction Predictor***

Not featured in this example, it seems theoretically possible that there could be an interaction between two Random Effect Numerical predictors. If this did happen, the interaction would be assigned a single column in the random effects design matrix, so how would lmer() estimate the variance of the random variable associated with this interaction? Thus, this question is similar to Question 2.

Comment: Your question is very long and contains multiple questions in one post. I would really narrow down your focus by a lot, which will improve the chances of someone actually providing an answer.

Comment: It is very long, I agree! The questions are all related to each other, so I put them together, however if nobody responds, then I will break it up into multiple posts. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this is one of the longest stack overflow questions I’ve ever seen and is pretty overwhelming for people to answer who are volunteering their free time. I’d agree with trimming this to something more manageable and digestible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "random variables" in a slightly nonstandard way.  You'd probably be better off thinking of the single outcome variable (that is being predicted, on the left side of the model equation) as the only random variable.  More specifically:

Q1: "should I think of all three columns of 1's in the random effects design matrix as being part of a single random variable, the Subject?"  This is certainly better than the 2nd option you mention, and almost correct.  Subjects are randomly selected and they are all part of the same random component of the model, but that doesn't make that component a random variable.

Q2: Yes, it is certainly possible to have a numerical predictor whose value is randomly determined, as in your rainfall example.  In this case lmer (and ancova) will attempt to predict the random outcome variable as a linear function of this numerical predictor.  It is not relevant to the model whether this numerical value was randomly determined (e.g., by nature) or experimentally controlled (e.g., by the experimenter's sprinkler system).

Q3: Days is a fixed effect (and keep in mind that this fixed effect refers to an effect on the average across all subjects--not a fixed value that is the same for all subjects).  The days:subject interaction term should be thought of like this: The day effect may vary randomly from subject-to-subject; this interaction term quantifies that random variation (which is extremely relevant in deciding whether or not the days effect in our sample can be generalized to the whole population average).

Q4: See Q3. "Is each column's parameter treated as a separate random variable?" Model parameters are not random variables as far as lmer is concerned (though model parameters are generally random variables to Bayesians).  The numerical values are used to estimate the model parameters (e.g., variance across Ss in the days effect).  But the model parameters themselves are constants fixed in nature that we are trying to estimate from the data.

Q5: I'm not sure how you are thinking that the interaction would be represented in a single column?  But lets go back to the rainfall example of Q2.  Maybe you measure one predictor that is the duration of rainfall and another that is the average rate of rainfall during periods of rain, so the "interaction" of these formed by multiplication is the total rainfall.  Again, if you include them in the model then lmer will try to predict the outcome variable as including linear contributions of these variables as well as the total rainfall, again without regard to whether these amounts were determined randomly or not.

It might really pay off to study ANOVA and ANCOVA models a bit more before getting into lmer. A lot of the same fundamental concepts are in play with those models, yet they are a bit simpler so it is easier to see how everything fits together.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response on this long post! You mention that a random effects predictor is a "random component", but I thought this was identical to a random variable, in the sense that lmer will model the levels of that predictor as random samples drawn from a distribution with some mean and variance?

Comment: Not really identical, no. One difference is that a single component (e.g., subject) may bring several individual random variables into the model, e.g., a random intercept, a random slope for each fixed factor effect, etc, (correlated or not).  This is a more complex set of random values than the single dependent random variable.  With respect to your Q1, maybe a more important distinction is that the multiple columns for coding subject are doing nothing except distinguishing the random components--they are not really themselves random values at all, but simply "dummy variable" codes.

Comment: Okay I think I understand, maybe I should make a purposeful distinction between (1) a random component due to the "main" effect of a random predictor, and (2) a random component due to an interaction with that random predictor. These two components would be associated with two separate terms in the linear model equation. In my example, there are thus two random components: (1) the Subject levels' intercepts, associated with the three 1's columns in the design matrix, and (2) the Subject:Days slopes, associated with the three [0,4,8] columns in the design matrix. Is this be more correct?Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that sounds right to me.  And the lmer output gives you the two corresponding separate estimates: the variability in the Ss' intercepts versus the variability in the Ss:Days slopes.